# How can I find out what plugin is missing in nmcli?

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm trying to reuse an old Asus EEE "a-la-RaspberryPi", as a small, single task unit.  Since I am familiar with Fedora, I have installed Fedora 27 on it via VNC (the default graphical installer is too big for the EEE screen), but I did not install any desktop environment (I don't need it, plus even LXDE would have required more disk space than the entire size of the EEE).

**During the installation I was able to connect to the Internet wirelessly** (after having configured from the installer the SSID and PWD for my home network).

**However, with the installed system, I am not**:

```
[mac@octoserver ~]$ nmcli
enp3s0: connected to enp3s0
    "Qualcomm Atheros Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet"
    ethernet (atl2), 00:1F:C6:ED:3B:D9, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.0.131/24
    inet6 fe80::26b6:a207:c3f7:8c89/64

lo: unmanaged
    "lo"
    loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

wlp1s0: unmanaged
    "Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (AW-GE780 802.11bg Wireless Mini PCIe Card)"
    wifi (ath5k), 00:15:AF:92:4E:2E, plugin missing, hw, mtu 1500

DNS configuration:
    servers: 192.168.0.1
    interface: enp3s0
```

The `plugin missing` is in bright red in the console, but I haven't been able to google or dnf anything up on what that is supposed to be...  `ath5k` seems to be an enabled module in my kernel, and I could not find any "plugin" package for nmcli in the repos...

Also confusing for me is the following:

```
[mac@octoserver ~]$ nmcli radio wifi
enabled
[mac@octoserver ~]$ nmcli device wifi list
[mac@octoserver ~]$
```

The radio [of a device, I guess] is ON but there is no device?!

**Any idea on what is going on?**

For completeness:

```
[mac@octoserver ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 04)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 04)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 04)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 04)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev d4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) SATA Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Attansic L2 Fast Ethernet (rev a0)
```

Comment: Try `dnf install NetworkManager-wifi`

Comment: @fpmurphy1 - Put that as an answer and I'll accept it! :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Centos7 fresh installed.  I tried dnf install NetworkManager-wifi but dnf is not installed.  The installer was able to connect to wifi.  Is there another way or do I need to connect via Ethernet and install?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably missing the `NetworkManager-wifi` package.

```
# dnf install NetworkManager-wifi
```

To apply changes, restart `NetworkManager.service`:

```
# systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Installing this caused NetworkManager to break with error "dependency". Whatever that means

Comment: I get an error because I'm not connected to wifi

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 7, the package manager is `yum`. Simply replace `dnf` with `yum`:

```
$ sudo yum install NetworkManager-wifi
```